# Changing values of a sub array

Tags: php, arrays

This program takes a bunch of NFL player's stats, calculates their passing rates and then displays all of the information. It's mostly completed but I'm having trouble in a few different areas.

```
$rate = "";
$file = 'purposely took the file location out';
$fp = fopen($file, 'r');
$name = "";
$team = "";
$completions = "";
$attempts = "";
$yards = "";
$touchdowns = "";
$interceptions = "";

function getNflStats($file){
@ $fp = fopen($file, 'r');


if(!$fp){
    echo "Could not open the file!<br/>";
    exit;
}

$nflStats = array();

while($data = fgetcsv($fp,255,',')){
    $name = $data[0];
    $team = $data[1];
    $completions = $data[2];
    $attempts = $data[3];
    $yards = $data[4];
    $touchdowns = $data[5];
    $interceptions = $data[6];
    $rate = Calculate($completions, $attempts, $yards, $touchdowns, 
    $interceptions);
    $nflStats[] = array("name"=>$rate);
}
fclose($fp);
return $nflStats;
}
```

How do I go about changing the values in a sub-array? Within the calculate function I have created an array that holds all of my calculated values. Through lots of attempts, I figured out that each of those values $a,$b,$c, and $d is its own array because of the while loop. I'm trying to check whether any value in any of the sub-arrays is above 2.375 or below 0 and if so, I will then change that value to be 2.375 or 0. I've been working on this for 3 hours but have yet to find a solution on how to run through each of the sub-arrays and change each individual element.

```
function Calculate($completions, $attempts, $yards, $touchdowns, 
$interceptions){
$a = ($completions/$attempts - .3) * 5;
$b = ($yards/$attempts - 3) * .25;
$c = ($touchdowns/$attempts) * 20;
$d = (2.375 - ($interceptions/$attempts *25));

$result = array($a,$b,$c,$d);
echo "$result[0] <br/>";
$size = count($result[0]);
foreach($result as $value){
  for($i=0;$i < $size; $i++){
    if($result[i] > 2.375){
            $result[i] = 2.375;
    }
  }
}
$passRating = round((($a + $b + $c + $d)/6) * 100, 2);

return $passRating;
}
```

I'm also having trouble displying the player's name and they're passing rate. I can only ever produce one or the other but not both at the same time. I'm unsure whether its an issue with my array formatting or foreach loop.

```
function displayStats($nflStats){

    asort($nflStats);

    echo "<table>";
    echo "<thead><tr>
       <td><h2>Player</h2></td>
       <td></td>
       <td><h2>Rating</h2></td>
       </tr></thead>";

    foreach($nflStats as $stats){
        echo "<tr>
            <td>{$stats['name']}</td>
            <td></td>
            <td style='text-align:right'></td>
          </tr>";
    }

    echo "</table>";
}

displayStats($nflStats);
?>
```

Here is some of the data that I'm reading from the file:

```
Tom Brady,NE,385,581,4577,32,8
Philip Rivers,LAC,360,575,4515,28,10
Matthew Stafford,DET,371,565,4446,29,10
Drew Brees,NO,386,536,4334,23,8
Ben Roethlisberger,PIT,360,561,4251,28,14
Matt Ryan,ATL,342,529,4095,20,12
Kirk Cousins,WAS,347,540,4093,27,13
Alex Smith,KC,341,505,4042,26,5
Russell Wilson,SEA,339,553,3983,34,11
Jared Goff,LA,296,477,3804,28,7
Blake Bortles,JAX,315,523,3687,21,13
Case Keenum,MIN,325,481,3547,22,7
Jameis Winston,TB,282,442,3504,19,11
Derek Carr,OAK,323,515,3496,22,13
Eli Manning,NYG,352,571,3468,19,13
Dak Prescott,DAL,308,490,3324,22,13
Andy Dalton,CIN,297,496,3320,25,12
Cam Newton,CAR,291,492,3302,22,16
Carson Wentz,PHI,265,440,3296,33,7
Marcus Mariota,TEN,281,453,3232,13,15
Joe Flacco,BAL,352,549,3141,18,13
Jacoby Brissett,IND,276,469,3098,13,7
Josh McCown,NYJ,267,397,2926,18,9
```

Currently I'm getting a bunch of errors regarding the variable i or just the values show:

sample of values: (trying to get them to not be negative or over ~158)

-12.8
-11.25
27.08
31.25
31.77
35.42
46.65
55.06
55.85
60.5
63.39
65.79
66.39
68.15
69.23
70.6
71.44
71.92
71.92
71.99
72.34
72.47
72.53
73.3
75.61
76.37
76.88
77.5
172.92
206.25
214.58
254.17
268.75
577.08
631.25

Comment: Please provide some sample input data (give us the contents of a file -- minimal length please) and your expected result from the sample data so that we can develop and test our solutions (this will make your question "complete").

Comment: Okay, will do then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to put the dollar sign in front of `i` in a couple of places, but I've mostly rewritten your code to try to streamline it for you. `asort()` was ordering ASC and preserving the keys -- but you didn't need to preserve the keys.  If you want ASC ordering with my new `usort()` method, just reverse the `$a` and `$b` variables on either side of the spaceship operator (`<=>`).

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/9ULHr))

```
$csv=<<<CSV
Tom Brady,NE,385,581,4577,32,8
Philip Rivers,LAC,360,575,4515,28,10
Matthew Stafford,DET,371,565,4446,29,10
Drew Brees,NO,386,536,4334,23,8
Ben Roethlisberger,PIT,360,561,4251,28,14
Matt Ryan,ATL,342,529,4095,20,12
Kirk Cousins,WAS,347,540,4093,27,13
Alex Smith,KC,341,505,4042,26,5
Russell Wilson,SEA,339,553,3983,34,11
Jared Goff,LA,296,477,3804,28,7
Blake Bortles,JAX,315,523,3687,21,13
Case Keenum,MIN,325,481,3547,22,7
Jameis Winston,TB,282,442,3504,19,11
Derek Carr,OAK,323,515,3496,22,13
Eli Manning,NYG,352,571,3468,19,13
Dak Prescott,DAL,308,490,3324,22,13
Andy Dalton,CIN,297,496,3320,25,12
Cam Newton,CAR,291,492,3302,22,16
Carson Wentz,PHI,265,440,3296,33,7
Marcus Mariota,TEN,281,453,3232,13,15
Joe Flacco,BAL,352,549,3141,18,13
Jacoby Brissett,IND,276,469,3098,13,7
Josh McCown,NYJ,267,397,2926,18,9
CSV;

function Calculate($completions, $attempts, $yards, $touchdowns, $interceptions){
    $result=[
        min(2.375, ($completions/$attempts - .3) * 5),
        min(2.375, ($yards/$attempts - 3) * .25),
        min(2.375, $touchdowns/$attempts * 20),
        min(2.375, 2.375 - ($interceptions/$attempts *25))
    ];
    // min() will ensure that no value will exceed 2.375 (avoiding looped conditional entirely)
    return round(array_sum($result)/6*100, 2);  // calculated passingRate
}

// foreach()...explode()...str_csv() is just for demo'ing purposes, you can use your existing process
foreach(explode("\n",$csv) as $line){
    list($name,$team,$completions,$attempts,$yards,$touchdowns,$interceptions)=str_getcsv($line,",");
    $NFL_Stats[]=['team'=>$team,'name'=>$name,'passingRate'=>Calculate($completions, $attempts, $yards, $touchdowns, $interceptions)];
}
usort($NFL_Stats,function($a,$b){return $b['passingRate']<=>$a['passingRate'];});  // order by passingRate DESC
var_export($NFL_Stats);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'team' => 'KC',
    'name' => 'Alex Smith',
    'passingRate' => 104.74,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'team' => 'NO',
    'name' => 'Drew Brees',
    'passingRate' => 103.87,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'team' => 'NE',
    'name' => 'Tom Brady',
    'passingRate' => 102.75,
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'team' => 'PHI',
    'name' => 'Carson Wentz',
    'passingRate' => 101.86,
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    'team' => 'LA',
    'name' => 'Jared Goff',
    'passingRate' => 100.48,
  ),
  5 => 
  array (
    'team' => 'DET',
    'name' => 'Matthew Stafford',
    'passingRate' => 99.33,
  ),
  6 => 
  array (
    'team' => 'MIN',
    'name' => 'Case Keenum',
    'passingRate' => 98.3,
  ),
  7 => 
  array (
    'team' => 'LAC',
    'name' => 'Philip Rivers',
    'passingRate' => 95.96,
  ),
  8 => 
  array (
    'team' => 'SEA',
    'name' => 'Russell Wilson',
    'passingRate' => 95.39,
  ),
  9 => 
  array (
    'team' => 'NYJ',
    'name' => 'Josh McCown',
    'passingRate' => 94.51,
  ),
  10 => 
  array (
    'team' => 'WAS',
    'name' => 'Kirk Cousins',
    'passingRate' => 93.85,
  ),
  11 => 
  array (
    'team' => 'PIT',
    'name' => 'Ben Roethlisberger',
    'passingRate' => 93.37,
  ),
  12 => 
  array (
    'team' => 'TB',
    'name' => 'Jameis Winston',
    'passingRate' => 92.24,
  ),
  13 => 
  array (
    'team' => 'ATL',
    'name' => 'Matt Ryan',
    'passingRate' => 91.36,
  ),
  14 => 
  array (
    'team' => 'DAL',
    'name' => 'Dak Prescott',
    'passingRate' => 86.64,
  ),
  15 => 
  array (
    'team' => 'CIN',
    'name' => 'Andy Dalton',
    'passingRate' => 86.59,
  ),
  16 => 
  array (
    'team' => 'OAK',
    'name' => 'Derek Carr',
    'passingRate' => 86.36,
  ),
  17 => 
  array (
    'team' => 'JAX',
    'name' => 'Blake Bortles',
    'passingRate' => 84.68,
  ),
  18 => 
  array (
    'team' => 'IND',
    'name' => 'Jacoby Brissett',
    'passingRate' => 81.67,
  ),
  19 => 
  array (
    'team' => 'CAR',
    'name' => 'Cam Newton',
    'passingRate' => 80.69,
  ),
  20 => 
  array (
    'team' => 'BAL',
    'name' => 'Joe Flacco',
    'passingRate' => 80.42,
  ),
  21 => 
  array (
    'team' => 'NYG',
    'name' => 'Eli Manning',
    'passingRate' => 80.37,
  ),
  22 => 
  array (
    'team' => 'TEN',
    'name' => 'Marcus Mariota',
    'passingRate' => 79.27,
  ),
)
```